# Frame rates: 3D view port vs VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, frame-rate

I created a 1.5-minute-long animation of a 3D model that rotates it to various orientations. The animation was rendered to .png image files using 24 fps. The animation runs as expected in the 3D view port. When I add the images into the VSE the animation runs much slower, around 9-10 fps. Render setting are shown the screen capture image. Any suggestions about how to work through this would be greatly appreciated.
[image: RenderSettingsScreenCapture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 3d view you may be playing only the OpenGL version of the scene, for example in textured or material mode or even just wireframe. Blender is optimised for this and it takes relatively little memory. This will play very fast.

After rendering to a high resolution image sequence you are asking Blender to load into memory a lot more data to display. Try selecting the strip and and creating a proxy, define the resolution and timecode type in the strip properties panel. The rebuild proxy/TC function is in the Strip menu at the bottom of the VSE timeline. Then go to the VSE preview window properties (N-key) and select the proxy size to view. Proxies of your footage should play back properly (less memory and processing overhead).

Alternatively go to the Blender timeline (not the VSE) and change the playback mode to AV-Sync. This will prioritise playback to frame rate and drop frames to do so.

Comment: There's a selection of, "Rebuild Proxy and Timecode Indices," in the Strip menu. I chose that but it didn't seem to help. On the other hand, selecting AV-Sync in the Playback menu made it work, i.e. getting video and audio synchronized. It sounds obvious, now, but it is so easy to get lost in all the options/possibilities in Blender. Your suggestions were much appreciated.

Comment: Oops forgot to mention that you must turn on Proxy view in the VSE preview window for that to work. I'll amend the answer ;-)